# Test for memory issues with website on a device?

Tags: javascript, debugging, device

I'm having a issue which is hard to debug. I'm using a Javascript library (the JQuery Flexslider plugin) in a number of different places on my site. It's all working fine except for one particular phone where it doesn't work and slows down everything on the page.

So far, I've only seen it happen on this one device. Other devices of the same type do not have the issue. This person has an iOS that's a few versions out of date and not much memory, so I think it's a memory issue.

An old hack was to move the carousel element that has the issue on the page with Javascript, but I want to find and fix the root issue.

How can I start debugging this? I'm not sure how to test for a memory issue on a device.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a memory issue at all. Old phone also has older, slower CPU and GPU. I think it's more likely due to that. Best way to get good performance is to not use jQuery, but often that's not an option. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol OK how do I debug any of these 'performance' issues? At the moment im just going on a hunch and I dont know how much of an edge case this is.

Comment: @Steve the chrome perf tools arent going to be much help for ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Mac, then you can plug in and use remote debugging via Safari, where you'll have access to the tools, including the profiler (not sure the state of Safari support in Windows). There are numerous resources for showing how to remotely debug a device, unless it is a *really* old version of iOS you should be fine, you’ll have to enable the `develop` menu via settings but after that its plain sailing if you know your debugging tools.

I'd agree that it doesnt really sound like a memory issue, although jQuery tends to be hungry in that respect, I dont know the plugin in question but the quality of plugins is hugely variable in jQuery-land. Old phones and old versions of jQuery certainly never played well together.

When you say one phone, you mean one type of phone + iOS version? The question isnt clear, its almost reads like you have 2 identical phones/os's where 1 works and 1 does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome you can use the Heap profiler

First open your developer tool and start recording.

[image: Heap]

Next start using your page and try to replicate your issue, stop recording and review the stats.

[image: Review]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not a memory issue, but a cpu issue. The way jQuery does animation is processor constrained on older dvices. Factors that are easiest to handle include:

- size of the page (html length and complexity)
- animation steps, length, and complexity

You have a couple of options here, but the simple answer is you are asking too much of the older processor. Assuming you are using this plugin http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ you could try disabling or simplifying some of the transition effects. `animation` and `animationSpeed` would be the first I would suggest.

If you are interested in not changing the experience for most users you could consider tying into the start and end functions on the callback api and checking the time it took to perform the first transition, then reinitialize a simpler version of the slideshow for that device.

The hard thing here is there isn't really a right answer. If one of the above options doesn't fix it you're likely looking at choosing/building a different slideshow, degrading the experience for everyone, or determining the best way you feel comfortable with choosing who gets the degraded experience.